# Creating table at runtime and storing data in it

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to create a table at the runtime and store information into it. 
Below the code which i tried.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
con.Open();
String crt = "CREATE TABLE trail (Name Varchar(50) NOT NULL, Sex Varchar(50) NOT NULL)";
SqlCommand cov = new SqlCommand(crt, con);
cov.ExecuteReader();
String add = "Insert into trail value (@nam,@sex)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(add,con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nam",TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", RbtGender.SelectedValue);
cmd.ExecuteReader();
con.Close();
Response.Redirect("Success.aspx");
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: I am Encountered with error (There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first) near cmd.ExecuteReader() statement

Comment: @Partha Did you read my answer? You don't need `ExecuteReader`!

Comment: I updated my code with ExecuteNonQuery. As you suggested I also used Add method instead of AddWithValue now im getting error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated. Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value). go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'

Comment: @Partha Yes. `Add(string, object)` is obsolete method anyway. But you can still use `Add(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType)` overload. For example; `cmd.Parameters.Add("@nam", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point to use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `CREATE` statement. It does not return any data anyway (and it retursn [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is not a `void` method). Use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead to execute your queries. Same with `INSERT` statement also.

And it is `values` not `value`. Take a look at [INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) syntax.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` like;

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand cov = con.CreateCommand())
{
   //
}
```

Don't use `AddWithValue` by the way. Use [one of `Add` overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx). This method has some problems.

Read: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but im encountered with following error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValues' and no extension method 'AddWithValues' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Partha It's `AddWithValue` not `AddWithValues`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code before
cmd.Connection = con;

Then I wrote this
cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: hi, this is not a clear answer, please look at the accepted one for guidance how an answer should look like :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).